# `new` in Spring boot controller is bad practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, new-operator

On a training I heard several times that `new` in controller or in service in Spring boot application is bad practice because it can cause a memory leak. And one told us to use Lombok

Lombok is great tool but I'm wondering about memory leaks with `new`. Moreover, if I use delombok I see the same `new` keyword there.

As far as I know garbage collector will delete all objects that are not referenced anymore. And this includes Spring boot controllers too. I don't speak about static variables, not closed streams, etc. Just a local variable in controller method.

Please tell me if I'm wrong and if I don't understand something correctly.

Comment: Yes. new is bad. Not for only memory leak but it also matters in best coding practices.

Comment: This is way too broad. You can't just say "new is bad" and leave it at that.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. new is bad since in this case spring can not manage these beans who are created by new operator

Comment: @spandey15 but not everything is a bean. You can freely create objects with `new` unless they should be included in the context, but not everything needs to be.

Comment: @ Kayaman you are right. my intention was just for beans not for POJO's. there we need new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On a training I heard several times that new in controller or in
>   service in Spring boot application is bad practice because it can
>   cause a memory leak. And one told us to use Lombok

Creating objects in our spring beans with the `new` operator and using Lombok are really two different things while the primary goal are different : creating an object for the first one versus generating code in the compiled class to reduce boiler plate code.

> I don't speak about static variables, not closed streams, etc. Just a
>   local variable in controller method.

About what you understood concerning the `new` operator, you should just forget and understand that at each time you have to create an object that is not a bean managed by a container you have to use the `new` operator.
For example how do you want to persist an entity in database without creating it ?
Besides local variables live the span of the method invocation.  So no memory leak is likely but if you create millions of big objects in your method. But why the hell would you do that ?